# execute command on remote machine

Tags: c#, wmi

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope( "\\\my_server\\root\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
```

How do I run a batch file on my_server d:\tools? I have tried:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope( "\\\my_server\\d\\tools");
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Never done it with WMI, but when I need to run a file remotely I usually use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Comment: Try http://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/ it's like PsExec but without the bugs.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow - how to execute file on D:\tools?

Comment: I was expecting to see an even number of backslashes... I think `\\\m` would be `\[undefined?]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Here's an example of its use: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257364(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257364%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Example:

```
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(@"\\<remotecomputername>\root\cimv2:Win32_Process");
ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

inParams["CommandLine"] = "calc.exe";
inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"c:\windows\system32";

ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

Comment: How to change the directory?

Comment: The create method has a CurrentDirectory argument

Comment: I am confused. Can you give me example?

Comment: thanks. it works. I created a simple bat file and it works. However when I run it against big install file. it doesnt do anything. is there a time out or anything?

Comment: Could be related to UAC. You may want to try disabling UAC or running with the built in Administrator account.